How do I connect 1-1/4” copper drain pipe to 1-1/2” PVC?
I need to connect 1-1/4” copper drain pipe to 1-1/2” PVC. It also needs a 90° horizontal turn so I’ll be using a long sweep 90° PVC elbow. Do they make reducing elbows?
This copper pipe is threaded into an iron drain and impossible to unscrew due to rust. I’m afraid of breaking that vertical iron pipe.

they make adapters for that

There's no need to adapt in the elbow, either. Make the corner with a PVC elbow, then reduce and adapt to the copper pipe. You can (I'd guess, absent a picture) always cut the copper pipe back to make room for an adapter.

Is this for a trap assembly under a sink?  If so consider adapting to 1-1/4 inch trap kit and not glued up PVC.  Still needs an adapter, just easier to build and maintain after that.

Use a rubber reducer to attach the 1 1/4 to 1 1/2 copper to PVC. These are readily available at the big box and hardware stores.
The 90 deg, sweep will have to come after the change to PVC.
There are reducer bushings also. They can be found in the same location as the rubber reducer connector.

Don't some situations require Fernco-type couplers to be shielded?

Maybe maybe not...we don't know the OPs situation.  In my local if the fitting isn't underground it doesn't need to be shielded.
